How can I prevent preprocessor values of _MBCS and _AFXDLL being inherited in an MSVC project
In my projects I am finding inherited C++ preprocessor values I don't want such as _MBCS and _AFXDLL
How to get rid of them?
David

They are project settings, Project > Properties > Advanced to change.  AFXDLL is set by "Use of MFC", MBCS is set by "Character Set".
